# AppInsights reachable check from internal Web

Tags: c#, web, firewall, azure-application-insights

I would like to ask you if you know how to make (at least idea) check on my internal Web (c# .netcore) if I can reach AppInsights.
The purpose is to check if firewall is blocking reachable to AppInsights.

Thank you. Problem is that my web is changing places of hosting - its a reason why I need web (cshtml) visualization if I can reach AppInsights.
Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have you configured application insights(via sdk) with the web project? If yes, just run the web project, and then check if there are some related logs in azure portal -> your application insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can try:

**Method 1**:

If the web project has been configured with application insights, just run the web project, and then nav to azure portal -> your application insights, see if the telemetry data are collected; Or you can use tools like `Fiddler`, when running the web project, check the response of application insights.

**Method 2**:

Check if these firewall exceptions are set, sample like below:

```
https://dc.services.visualstudio.com:443
```

For more details, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/faq#can-i-monitor-an-intranet-web-server) and [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses).

Comment: I got advice from one of my colleagues: 
- use just simple "ping"
- use any request from app to appInsights and see if I will get response 200 or diff

Comment: To be more specified, I have AppInsight and outside is all of this is web on which I am trying to check if this web can reach AppInsight... (its mean ping? or Request 200/500?) any ideas? I dont think that I can put anything on AppInsith side, so I need to put it on web side and check if I can reach or not

Comment: @user3132499, what do you mean "I dont think that I can put anything on AppInsith side, so I need to put it on web side and check if I can reach or not"? And is the web app configured with application insights?

Comment: For the "ping", if the web app is configured with application insights, yes, you can check the response(good or bad response code) of the requests to application insights.

Comment: Ping is working well, problem is that I dont know the IP adress of AppInsights, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses  there is xx IP address for many regions, have no idea if I should just check half of them and hope that some of them will reach - but its not good solution. Or I got a hind about check adress of "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.EndpointAddress" which have no idea too....

Comment: @user3132499, just use this command: `ping dc.services.visualstudio.com`

Comment: Did, thanks! Now I am trying to solve the second way with HttpWebRequest. Problem is that I have a 405 (method not allowed)  response. And I would like to handle it fancier than just catch the exception and check the type of exception...

Comment: try
            {
                var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_endPointUri);
                myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = _timeoutMs;
                var myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return true;
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                return e.Message.Contains("The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.");
            }

Comment: @user3132499, do you still have more issues?